# What does this Javascript object syntax means? It has a key (a string) and a value (object)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am following a tutorial on Youtube about importing data into existing todo list component in React.

If you look at the code below, at the `const data` object, there are two keys namely lists and listIds. There are two parts which I don't understand.

1. Why is the key `"list-1"` a string while the value `{id: "list-1",title: "Todo",cards,}`
   is a normal object? I could not figure out this syntax. If it's JSON format, both key-value should be a in quotation marks.
2. Is the `listIds: ["list-1"]` just a normal key-value pair which has an array as its value? If so, why does it has the same name as the one from the initial lists keys? Is this a Destructuring method from ES6?. I just cannot understand the syntax.

```js
const cards = [
              {
                id: "card-1",
                title: "Learning how to cook",
              },
              {
                id: "card-2",
                title: "Making sandwich",
              },
              {
                id: "card-3",
                title: "Taking the trash out",
              },
            ];
        
        const data = {
          lists: {
            "list-1": {
              id: "list-1",
              title: "Todo",
              cards,
            },
          },
          listIds: ["list-1"],
        };
        
        export default data;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because "list-1" contains a minus sign and that would be an error for an identifier name. It would be like trying to subtract 1 from "list" and use the expression as a key.

`listIds : ["list-1"]`  is a normal JS key-value expression with a key to the left of `:` and an array with a single string value to the right.

Object `data.lists` looks like it contains various sub-objects, each having an ID and `listIds` is just an array containing all the keys in `lists`. In your example there is one sub-object and correspondingly, one key in `listIds`.

One more thing: In a JSON string, keys to the left of `:` must be in double quotes, however this is a Javascript object, and Javascript objects can have keys without double quotes as long as each key is formatted as a regular Javascript variable, as well as values to the right of `:` that many times cannot be represented in a JSON string, such as functions for example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand the usage of the double quotes now. But, can we actually pass the key `list-1` into the array? Isn't it just gonna be a `list-1` string (without any value)? I understand if we can pass a `const` or and function but passing the key values of `list-1` still kinda hard for me to imagine unless there is a special rule that I don't know of.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this expression: `data.list[ data.listIds[0] ]` will access the sub-object under `data.list` referred to by the first element of the array `data.listIds`. A string is a value unto itself. Also look at the very nice analysis @jfriend00 added below.

Answer (score 3):

I just thought I'd add a little summary here about declaring key/value pairs in an object declaration.  When you declare an object property as in:

```
let obj = {prop: value};
```

the left hand side of the property declaration is the property name.  There are **three** possible syntaxes allowed for that:

**Plain String - No Quotes**

```
// no quotes - this is allowed when the property name 
// doesn't contain any reserved characters
let obj = {prop: value};
```

**Quoted String**

```
// quotes - this is always allowed, but is required when the property name
// does contain reserved characters like a "-" such as your example of "list-1"
let obj = {"prop": value};
```

**Brackets around a variable name**

```
// computed property name.  This is used when the property name you want to use
// is in a variable
let someVar = "prop";
let obj = {[someVar]: value};
```

All three of these options above create the exact same key/value pair in that object.

---

The right hand side of the `prop: value` pair can be any Javascript expression like these:

```
let obj = {prop: 3};                          // a number
let obj = {prop: "foo"};                      // a string
let obj = {prop: value};                      // value from some variable
let obj = {prop: [1,2,3]};                    // an array
let obj = {prop: resultFromCallingFunc()};    // the result from calling some function
let obj = {prop: {greeting: "hello"}};        // another object
let obj = {prop: 3 + 4};                      // any expression
```